# What is the error runaway argument in the following code?

Tags: debugging

Here is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\title{IELTS Course Companion}
\author{Ethen Hu}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\maketitle
\section{numbers}
\subsection{question\footnote{OG 3.1}}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\alph{enumi}}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 1st/3rd
    \item \$10.50/\$10.15
    \item 6th/5th
    \item 17/70
    \item 19/90
    \columnbreak
    \item 15/50
    \item 52/62
    \item \pounds110/\pounds810
    \item 31st/33rd
    \item 22nd/27th
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

%\subsection{question 2 \footnote{OG 3.3}






\end{document}
```

This is successfully compiled on overleaf, but with a warning:argument of@sect has an extra}. runaway argument?

This is the         [image]error page incase it is of anyhelp. I guess it has something to do with trying to put a footnote on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the optional argument to `subsection`, like this,

```
\subsection[question]{question\footnote{OG 3.1}}
```

lets you add the `\footnote` without fuss, and your example runs nicely.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would you please expand on what was wrong with my code what does the [question] argument do. Thanks so much.

Comment: I don't really know about what is happening behind the scenes, but you will find a range of more or less deep explanations in the usual literature, e.g. [Nasa pages](https://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/latex/ltx-141.html]). If you can get hold of a copy of the The LaTeX Companion (2nd edn.), it's great for this kind of explanation, but you should be able to find a lot online.

Answer (score 0):

```
 \title{IELTS Course Companion}
 \author{Ethen Hu}

 \begin{document}

  \maketitle

   \section{numbers}
    \subsection{question}
      {\footnote{OG 3.1}}


   \begin{tabular}{cc}
    $ 1^{st}$ & $3^{rd}$\\
    \$ 10.50 &\$ 10.15\\
    $ 6^{th}$ & $5^{th}$\\
    17 & 70\\
    19& 90\\
     &\\
   15 & 50\\
    52 & 62\\
    Lb 110 &  Lb 810\\
    $31^{st}$ & $33^{rd}$\\
   $22^{nd}$ & $27^{th}$\\
   \end{tabular}


   \end{document}
```

I thought this is what you. Multicolumn are meant for tabular environment and item for enumuration. Please check whether this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\title{IELTS Course Companion}
\author{Ethen Hu}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\alph{enumi}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\maketitle
\section{numbers}
\subsection{question 1}{\footnote{OG 3.1}}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 1st/3rd
\item $10.50/$10.15
\item 6th/5th
\item 17/70
\item 19/90
\columnbreak
\item 15/50
\item 52/62
\item \pounds110/\pounds810
\item 31st/33rd
\item 22nd/27th
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\subsection{question 2} {\footnote{OG 3.3}}

\end{document}
% I rearranged statements. It works fine. I moved the statements \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\alph{enumi}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} before begin document. This isthe place for all commands.